# can we prevent/avoid gps spoofing?

Tags: android, gps

Is it possible that any external "hacker" can hack my app which is using gps tracker by using gps spoofing? Is it possible to prevent it? Thinking particularly for android devices and related apps those are using gps widely!

Answer (score 0):

not sure about preventing it, but device being able to be spoofed, should have it's setting enabled which can be read by this method:

```
private boolean isMockEnabled() {
        return !Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0");
    }
```

my approach was to alert the admin, or prevent the application when Mock is available